# List all my youtube video with Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api, youtube-api

I have some problem to list my youtube video list in my spreadsheet.
'maxResults' value's max is just 50. so, I cannot list more than 50 videos!
How to I get all of my youtube videos?

```
function searchListMine(part, params, pageToken) {
  params = removeEmptyParams(params); // See full sample for function
  var response = YouTube.Search.list(part, params);
  var title = "";
  var id = "";
  var lr = 0;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var nextPageToken = 'nextPageToken';
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("시트2");

  Logger.log(response.items.length)
  for (var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++) {
      var item = response.items[i];
      title = item.snippet.title;
      id = item.id.videoId;
      lr = sheet1.getLastRow() + 1;
      sheet1.getRange(lr, 1).setValue(title);
      sheet1.getRange(lr, 2).setValue(id);
      lr++;
    }

}

function Main() {
  searchListMine('snippet', {'maxResults': '50',
                             'forMine': 'true',
                             'type': 'video',
                            });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> [nextPageToken](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) string
>
> The token that can be used as the value of the pageToken parameter to retrieve the next page in the result set.

The  nextPageToken is part of the response returned to you by the api.  You will need to add this to the parms part of your request using the PageToken parameter.

Probably something like this.

```
var optionalArgs = {forMine:'true', type: 'video', maxResults: 50,  pageToken: pageToken}
```

> pageToken  string
>
> The pageToken parameter identifies a specific page in the result set that should be returned. In an API response, the nextPageToken and prevPageToken properties identify other pages that could be retrieved.

Then loop your requests until nextpagetoken is returned null.